# Using SubstituteKey with Joined Table

Tags: acumatica

I have a selector defined in this manner:

```
[PXSelector(typeof(Search2<TableA.id, LeftJoin<TableB, On<TableB.refNbr, Equal<TableA.refNbr>>>,
    Where<TableA.woid, IsNull, And<TableB.tranType, Equal<TranType>, And<TableB.lotSerialNbr, NotEqual<StringEmpty>>>>>),
      typeof(TableA.id), typeof(TableB.lotSerialNbr), SubstituteKey = typeof(TableB.lotSerialNbr))]
```

However the selector does not show the SubstituteKey value. Am I able to assign the SubsistiteKey belonging to a joined table instead of the original table and show/fetch its value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported to assign the SubsistiteKey to a joined table field. As an alternative, let me suggest to declare an unbound field in TableA and decorate it with the PXDBScalarAttribute to calculate its value on database level:

```
[PXDBScalar(typeof(Search<TableB.lotSerialNbr, <TableB.refNbr, Equal<TableA.refNbr>>>))]
```

Comment: Thanks Ruslan. I ended up rewriting how the join works, but I understand what you were trying to do here. If I run into another issue using the data, I will look deeper into using this PXSBScalar functionality, but for now I wasn't completely able to get it to work.